# How to retrieve the user's Google Account. select account?

Tags: java, android, android-service, google-oauth

Excuse me for my English.
According to the new [Google account api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start)

Upon receipt of user data from Google Account, user need to choose your account in the pop-up window (screenshot below):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

To do this, use the following code :

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("RESULT_", requestCode + " ---- " +resultCode + " ---- " + data);
    hideProgressDialog();
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

It uses the following settings for the object GoogleSignInOption:

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

The question is - is there a way to bypass the selection dialog of the account, ie that this window does not show the user and automatic through software code loaded the first account from the list (if more than one, or if it is only one) ?

Comment: You can try silentSignIn method, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763857/6630837

Comment: and use that credential to auto login the user without showing the account chooser dialog.

Comment: thanks, I will try